# “Column count doesn't match value count at row 1”

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I've looked at different links (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704328/c-sharp-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)), but i still can't get where does this error message comes from. I keep on counting columns, comas and so on without finding where is the problem.

```
int exId = stride.getExerciseId();
string timestamp = stride.getTimeStamp();
int startSec = stride.getBeginningSec();
int startMsec = stride.getBeginningMSec();
int endSec = stride.getEndSec();
int endMSec = stride.getEndMSec();
float length = stride.getLength();
float duration = stride.getDuration();
float steplength = stride.getStepLength();
float stepDuration = stride.getStepDuration();
string supportingFoot = stride.getSupportingFoot();

string query = "INSERT INTO singlesupportstate (ExerciseId , TimeStamp , SingleSupportStateStartSeconds , SingleSupportStateStartMSeconds , SingleSupportStateEndSeconds , SingleSupportStateEndMSeconds , StrideLength , StrideDuration , StepLength , StepDuration , SupportingFoot) 
VALUES("+ exId +",'" + timestamp +"',"+ startSec +"," + startMsec + "," + endSec + "," + endMSec + "," + length +"," + duration + "," + steplength + "," + duration + ",'" + supportingFoot + "')";
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     this.CloseConnection();
}
```

**EDIT :**

So I changed my code in order to use Parameterized query, here is the new code that works:

```
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand() ;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO singlesupportstate (ExerciseId , TimeStamp , SingleSupportStateStartSeconds , SingleSupportStateStartMSeconds , SingleSupportStateEndSeconds , SingleSupportStateEndMSeconds , StrideLength , StrideDuration , StepLength , StepDuration , SupportingFoot) "
                +" VALUES(@exId,@timestamp,@startSec,@startMsec,@endSec,@endMSec,@length,@duration,@steplength,@stepduration,@supportingFoot)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@exId", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@timestamp",MySqlDbType.Timestamp);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@startMsec",MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@startSec",MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@endSec",MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@endMSec",MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@length", MySqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@duration",MySqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@steplength",MySqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stepduration", MySqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@supportingfoot", MySqlDbType.Text);

            cmd.Parameters["@exId"].Value = exId;
            cmd.Parameters["@timestamp"].Value = timestamp;
            cmd.Parameters["@startMsec"].Value = startMsec;
            cmd.Parameters["@startSec"].Value = startSec;
            cmd.Parameters["@endSec"].Value = endSec;
            cmd.Parameters["@endMSec"].Value = endMSec;
            cmd.Parameters["@length"].Value = length;
            cmd.Parameters["@duration"].Value = duration;
            cmd.Parameters["@steplength"].Value =steplength;
            cmd.Parameters["@stepduration"].Value =stepDuration;
            cmd.Parameters["@supportingfoot"].Value =supportingFoot;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
```

Comment: You should be using parametrized queries here, It might be possible that one of the parameters has a extra `'` or something like that

Comment: It's possible that one of the values you are using is either causing SQL to think you've got more values than columns. Can you print out what value 'query' has? What does that say?

Comment: Try outputting your query string or viewing it in the debugger. If you don't see a problem please post the query string and your singlesupportstate table structure with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is likely happening is one of two things:

1) There are `'` quotes making your query seem it has fewer values, because it eats up the commas.
2) There are numbers being formatted with a comma rather than a point, resulting in the number `123.45` showing as `123,45`, thus making the query think there are two integer values: `123` and `45` resulting in too many values.

As others have said, try and use query parameters and this won't happen again. It also saves you a lot of manual escaping of strings.

Comment: After looking more closely at the query string it seems that the float's commas are the reasons of my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This means that in one of the values in the concatenation is breaking the INSERT because it has a comma or string delimiter, thus breaking the whole `query` string

Look at the actual `query` string *after* concatenation, *before* execution

And use parameters to remove *this* problem anyway and mitigate SQL injection risks.

The other option is a trigger (saym for audit or history) on the `singlesupportstate` table that has a broken INSERT too.

Comment: Is it possible than the commas from a float numbers lead to this exception ?

Comment: @FlorentGz: absolutely, yes. As I said *before* the accepted answer was posted